# IE6 CSS Issue on Visited Link

Tags: css, hyperlink, internet-explorer-6, visited

From my investigation, it seems like IE6 considers the following links are the same:

link1: http://www.google.com#/test=1
link2: http://www.google.com#/test=2

Reason being that I have assigned different colors between a:visited and a:link.

After the first click on link1 or link2, both links are rendered with a:visited color.

It does not happen on IE7 onwards though.

Have you guys encountered this issue before? If so, can someone please advise me the best way to resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you stated that you cannot avoid IE 6 (*sigh*), my answer is to avoid the problem entirely by implementing a more modern design without highlighting the visited links...   the unvisited link always looks the same as the visited link.

Has any large, popular or professional website in the last decade differentiated the "visited" links?  Answer: none that I recall.

**Why?**

1. People are treated more intelligently.  They already know they visited a link and don't need the site to tell them.
2. Websites are better organized.  A site with a clear layout is less confusing and people don't need a visual indication of what they've already clicked.
3. Graphics and visual clues.  Websites used to be mostly plain text with maybe a photo here and there.  You needed a visual indicator to help keep track of where you left off with your reading.  Especially since most links took you to a whole new page or website.  These days, content is visually rich with graphical layouts, icons, less text, animations, multimedia, etc... you no longer need to depend on the colored text of the "visited" indicator to help you keep track of where you left off.
4. Complexity and Ajax.  With the richly interactive pages available these days, page refreshing is not required to update content.  However, when you do need to refresh a page, people expect that page to return to it's initial "unvisited" state.  With the "visited" link, you cannot "reset" the page with a simple refresh and that will lead to confusion; especially since modern visitors are not expecting to see links change to a different color.
5. Confusing and inconsistent experience.  Anyone who started using the Internet within the last 5-10 years is probably not going to readily understand why certain links are suddenly different colors on your site and nobody else's.
6. Not all links are pages or sites.  Some links trigger a modal.  Some cause divs to open or slide around.  Some control a slideshow or other interactive object.  A link can trigger any ajax function you can think of.  Once clicked, are those links considered "visited" then too?  Of course not.  To reduce the confusion, the concept of a "visited" link is rendered obsolete.
7. Redundancy.  Most people these days use the same website on different computers, handheld devices, etc. therefore, the "visited link" is rendered useless anyway.  Not to mention that people tend to delete their cache and also use multiple browsers on the same machine, again rendering the highlighted color of the "visited link" pointless.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
           a:link, a:visited { color: black; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="yahoo.com#/test=1">Link1</a>; <a href="yahoo.com#/test=2">Link2</a>;
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**:  The recommendations made in my answer above were intended for links primarily used for site navigation, menus, footers, etc.  A valid exception would be links composing a list of search results.

Comment: I disagree. I personaly use the visual color change of visited sites often on sites like Google, Amazon, StackOverflow. For example, with a list of search results, I may click through one, decide it's not what I want, hit back, click another, etc. I may even refine my search and get a different list of results that overlaps with previous ones. It's very helpful when the links I've visited are a different color so I avoid revisiting ones I've already followed.

Comment: @CincinnatiJoe, yes, 'search result lists' would be an exception to the rule.  However, comments are not the appropriate place for discussions, arguments or disagreements.  (Is IE6 really still an issue for anyone?)

Answer (score 0):

This not answer to you question but Stop using IE6 it's out market now and most of the site stopped supporting IE6 its better to move on the next versions

here is link related to IE6 news : http://www.ianhoar.com/2011/06/17/ie6-is-dead-no-really-i-mean-it-this-time/

Comment: Rana, I know. but the client that we are supporting is still using IE6. what a pain :(

Comment: Well as per your question if possible past you code and than may be i try to figure out what went wrong ...

Comment: <html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
 a:visited { color: red; }
 a:link { color: black; }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<a href="http://www.yahoo.com#/test=1">Link1</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com#/test=2">Link2</a>

</body>


</html>

Comment: I downvoted you and will do the same with all such answers. Your answer is not relevant. If someone's asking a question related to IE6, he probably wants to or has to support IE6. You don't help the OP with these answers.